# What does this mean? A paragraph from Justice

Tags: meaning

Following is a part of a paragraph from [*Justice* by Michael J. Sandel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice:_What's_the_Right_Thing_to_Do%3F).

> To ask whether a policy will speed economic recovery or spur economic growth does not involve judging people's preferences. It assumes that everyone prefers more income rather than less, and it doesn't pass judgement on how they spend their money. Similiary, to ask whether, under conditions of duress, people are actually free to choose doesn't require evaluating their choices. The question is whether, or to what extent, people are free rather than coerced.

I couldn't get the meaning of this after minutes of trial. Could you break it down for a dummy?

Comment: Answering this question will take a considerable amount of work and might be considered as proofreading, which is off-topic here. It would be better if you asked several questions, each about a specific concern that you have with a particular sentence (or part of it); Note that asking "please explain this sentence" will elicit a similar response.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't surprise me that someone would have difficulty with that passage. It is convoluted and unnecessarily wordy. I recommend that you cut all unnecessary words and try again. I'll do the first sentence for you: [Making economic policy decision] does not involve knowing spending preference.